# Anylogic - Restart Simulation from a Button

Tags: button, model, anylogic

I would like to create a button that the user can press during model execution which stops the model and begins running it again from time = 0.

The following code *does* work, but only some of the time and will sometimes work for two or three presses of the button before the model just hangs.

```
pauseSimulation();
stopSimulation();
getExperiment().stop();
((Simulation) getExperiment()).button.action();
getExperiment().run();
```

This sometimes is associated with getEngine().getState() = PLEASE_WAIT, but not always.

I don't know if it's a timing issue, or that I should be doing things is a slightly different order, or with different phraseology.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify how your are starting your experiment the first time?  Are you using a button to start the first run or automatically starting the run?  There is a code snippet in the AnyLogic help menu about how to start an experiment automatically without requiring the button push.  How you are starting the first one would influence how I would recommend you implement this button.  I am assuming this restart button is on Main (or in model instance and not on experiment screen).

Comment: Hi.  Run is,
1) started from the 'white play symbol on a green circle' on the Anylogic menu bar,
2) then by pressing the Run button on Simulation: Main.
The button I want to place my code behind is then on Main and so accessible while the model is running.

Answer (score 0):

In your button action use

```
getExperiment().stop();
```

In your simulation experiment properties, in the Java Actions section, add the following to After Simulation Run:

```
run();
```